# The correct parsing of "than in the breath that from my mistress reeks"

Tags: sentence-structure, parsing, dangling-modifier

This one is a line from one of [Shakespeare's sonnets](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45108/sonnet-130-my-mistress-eyes-are-nothing-like-the-sun).
I don't get which is the subject, and which noun belongs to the prepositional 'from'.

My first interpretation is

"the breath that from [it] my mistress reeks"
i.e., the breath that the mistress reeks from. My other interpretation is
"The breath that (from my mistress) reeks"
i.e., the breath that reeks from the mistress. So which one the truer version?

Also I rarely see the verb "reeks" used with "from", but I often see it used with "of", for example, the abandoned basement reeks of dust. What does reeks from mean?

Comment: This is poetry, and it is 400 year old poetry.   Perhaps ask this question on Literarure.stackexchange.   But it just means the breath comes from his mistress, and it smells bad.

Comment: Yeah the latter interpretation seems more natural...

Comment: I don't feel literature stackexchange would be too happy with a grammar question.

Comment: By the way, the verb "reek" probably hadn't quite the meaning it has today. According to Etymonline the meaning "to emit a bad smell" is only recorded from 1710. In old Scottish it meant "to smoke" (as in the old toast "Lang may yer lum reek": long may your chimney smoke). The Sonnets were written between 1590 and 1605, at the time of the so-called Little Ice Age, when fairs were held on the frozen Thames. As most houses had little heating, you'd have been able to see each other's breath reeking, even indoors.

Comment: “than in the breath that from my mistress reeks” ...... nobody writes English that way anymore. That sentence is grammatically incorrect by contemporary standards. Literally, that is a poorly worded sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work you refer to was published in 1609 in England.  Language changes.

Sonnet 130

> My mistress' eyes are nothing like the sun;
>
> Coral is far more red than her lips' red;
>
> If snow be white, why then her breasts are dun;
>
> If hairs be wires, black wires grow on her head.
>
> I have seen roses damasked, red and white,
>
> But no such roses see I in her cheeks;
>
> **And in some perfumes is there more delight**
>
> **Than in the breath that from my mistress reeks.**
>
> I love to hear her speak, yet well I know
>
> That music hath a far more pleasing sound;
>
> I grant I never saw a goddess go;
>
> My mistress, when she walks, treads on the ground.
>
> And yet, by heaven, I think my love as rare
>
> As any she belied with false compare.

This is an independent clause:

> And in some perfumes is there more delight
>
> Than in the breath that from my mistress reeks.

But keep in mind that we are talking about poetry.  **The subject is *perfumes*, *in the breath* is a prepositional phrase that acts as an adverbial, and *that from my mistress reeks* modifies *breath*.**  The mistress does not smell bad-- it is her breath.

Comment: I meant by the subject, the subject of the smaller dependent phrase, the one that did the 'reeking', so you should add that to the answer. Did the mistress reek or did the breath reek? I could say "the plate that from my child eats", and it makes sense semantically, and also "the predator that from the corpse eats" also makes sense, but in the former the latter noun is the subject, and in the latter the former noun is the subject.

Comment: If you were to say, "The plate that from my child eats," this would be literary and remind everyone of Shakespeare.

Comment: @AngularOrbit  I edited my answer.

Comment: I don't think "the plate that from my child eats" makes sense, unless the plate is doing the eating. The construction is "the X that Y": "the water that flows," "the light that shines." The "that from" construction you're suggesting (as in "the tap that from the water flows") is ungrammatical. Someone smarter than me could probably explain why that is or what rule it breaks.

Comment: @d_b  Please recognize that we are talking about Shakespeare here.  This is literary language that is immediately recognizable as such.

Comment: @Patriot Sorry for the late response. Answer accepted. you must not think I am not up-voting, I did, my votes don't appear yet.

Comment: @d_b Yeah, "that from" as an synonym to "from which" doesn't really seem to be used anywhere. Somehow I thought it made sense. "The plate from which my child eats" is much more readable.